# For each integer what character does it map to?

Tags: c, gcc, character-encoding, byte, unsigned-char

Consider the `signed char` in C:

```
-128 represents what character?
-127 represents what character?
 ...
-1 represents what character?

0 represents the NULL character, right?
1 represents the SOH character, right?
...
127 represents the DEL character, right?
```

Next, consider the `unsigned char` in C:

```
0 represents the NULL character, right?
1 represents the SOH character, right?
...
127 represents the DEL character, right?

128 represents what character?
129 represents what character?
...
255 represents what character?
```

Are the sequence of characters represented by ***0*** to **127** in `signed char` the same sequence of characters represented by ***0*** to ***127*** in `unsigned char`?

Are the sequence of characters represented by ***-128*** to ***-1*** in `signed char` the same sequence of characters represented by ***128*** to ***255*** in `unsigned char`?

A `signed char` can represent ***256*** different characters, right?

An `unsigned char` can represent ***256*** different characters, right?

Thank you!

Comment: As long as the compiler uses 8-bit `char` values in two's complement notation, the ranges you suggest are correct. There might still be one's complement or sign-magnitude systems around, but you're relatively unlikely to find them. There were systems with, for example, 36-bit words, where the characters were 9-bit.  Some DSP systems use 16-bit char types. In both those cases, your assumptions are way off, but they're quite specialized. As to the mapping of characters, the only one that's fixed by the C standard is NUL `'\0'` which is character code 0; all the others are implementation defined.

Comment: @Jonathan Leffler  Nice! - minor clarification: `NUL` is an ASCII name for the C "null character" `'\0'`, not a C spec name.

Comment: @chux: Yes, you're correct — §7.1.1 Definition of terms (for the introduction to the library), the standard uses 'null character', and NUL is the standard abbreviation in ASCII for the zero byte. §6.4.5 String literals says 'In translation phase 7, a byte or code of value zero is appended to each multibyte
character sequence that results from a string literal or literals.78)' and footnote 78 says 'A string literal need not be a string (see 7.1.1), because a null character may be embedded in it by a
`\0` escape sequence.'

Answer (score 3):

Technically, it's implementation defined what code is assigned to what character. The implementation is allowed to use an arbitrary character encoding for strings on execution (called the *execution character set*) as long as it contains certain characters. In practice, every system you will see in an ordinary career will use ASCII for the execution character set, unless you are working on IBM mainframes, in which case you probably wouldn't ask this question.

Comment: "In practice, every system you will see in an ordinary career will use ASCII for the execution character set" Thanks! Doesn't ASCII have only 128 characters? What are the other 128 characters that can be represented in a signed char or unsigned char?

Comment: @RogerCostello The other 128 values a `char` can have don't have a corresponding character when ASCII is used. This is also why it's not really important to distinguish between a `signed char` and an `unsigned char` as the range from 128 to 255 isn't used anyway.

Answer (score 0):

- 0..127: Yes
- -128..-1: Yes
- Yes; a `char`, signed or not, is 8 bits, and 2^8 = 256
- Yes

Comment: No. `char` is *at least* 8 bits (cf. ISO 8899:2011§5.2.4.2.1). No, the system is not required to use ASCII. No, the system may use a signed integer representation other than two's complement. No, no, no.

Comment: Who said anything about ASCII?

Comment: The OP did: "127 represents the DEL character, right?"... That depends on the character set.

Comment: @Jongware: which would make the part about ASCII a comment more about the question than an answer which never refers to any particular character set, no?

Comment: Sure. The OP doesn't seem to know about this particular distinction, so why not educate 'im a bit.